# HDMI EDID emulator

Tags: arduino-uno

I am working on a project where i emulate the EDID of a screen to force a source into sending data on a certain resolution.

I read the original EDID code of a screen and change the timings into the resolution I want to force the source in, i send this changed EDID code to the source with an Arduino uno when the source gives a read on address 0x50 (where the EDID located, see handshake). We have an HDMI in/out with the data lines connected thru and the DDC lines (source) connected to the Arduino that we can send the changed EDID to the source (i²c protocol).

I can change the resolution successfully on some sources, and on some it doesn’t change. The attached screen doesn’t find a source. I use the same code for both scenarios.

```
#include <DTWI.h>
#include <Wire.h>         //BUFFER_LENGTH = 256

uint8_t edid[256] = {
 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x4C, 0x2D, 0xF4, 0x0C, 0x45, 0x52, 0x46, 0x31, 0x15, 0x19, 0x01, 0x03, 0x80, 0x3C, 0x22, 0x78, 0x2A, 0x52, 0x95, 0xA5, 0x56, 0x54, 0x9D, 0x25, 0x0E, 0x50, 0x54, 0xBF, 0xEF, 0x80, 0x71, 0x4F, 0x81, 0xC0, 0x81, 0x00, 0x81, 0x80, 0x95, 0x00, 0xA9, 0xC0, 0xB3, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x3A, 0x80, 0x18, 0x71, 0x38, 0x2D, 0x40, 0x58, 0x2C, 0x45, 0x00, 0x56, 0x50, 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x01, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x72, 0x51, 0xD0, 0x1E, 0x20, 0x6E, 0x28, 0x55, 0x00, 0x56, 0x50, 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFD, 0x00, 0x32, 0x4B, 0x1E, 0x51, 0x11, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFC, 0x00, 0x53, 0x32, 0x37, 0x45, 0x33, 0x37, 0x30, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x01, 0x62, 0x02, 0x03, 0x1B, 0xF1, 0x46, 0x90, 0x04, 0x1F, 0x13, 0x03, 0x12, 0x67, 0x03, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x80, 0x22, 0x23, 0x09, 0x07, 0x07, 0x83, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x1D, 0x00, 0xBC, 0x52, 0xD0, 0x1E, 0x20, 0xB8, 0x28, 0x55, 0x40, 0x56, 0x50, 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x8C, 0x0A, 0xD0, 0x90, 0x20, 0x40, 0x31, 0x20, 0x0C, 0x40, 0x55, 0x00, 0x56, 0x50, 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x8C, 0x0A, 0xD0, 0x8A, 0x20, 0xE0, 0x2D, 0x10, 0x10, 0x3E, 0x96, 0x00, 0x56, 0x50, 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3D
};  

void receiveEvent(int receivedByte)
{
    if (receivedByte == 1)          //If there is 1 byte received
    {
      int receivedValue = Wire.read() << 1;
      receivedValue |= Wire.read();
      Serial.print("Read byte: ");
      Serial.print(receivedValue); 
      Serial.println();
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Not the amount of bytes that was expected: ");
        Serial.print(receivedByte); 
    }  

    while(Wire.available())
    {
        Wire.read();
    }
    return;
}

void requestEvent()
{  
      Serial.println();

     for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            Wire.write(edid[i]);               //Write EDID
            Serial.print(edid[i], HEX);      //Print EDID
            Serial.print(",");  
     }

    Serial.println(); 
    Serial.println("Finished");      //Write is complete

}  

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  Serial.println("**** HDMI ****");
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);          //Hot plug detection
  Wire.begin(0x50);  
  digitalWrite(2, LOW); 
  delay(20);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);         //Source knows that a screen is attached and want to read the edid of the screen

  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);  
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); 
}

void loop()
{

}
```

The following attached pictures are the EDID handshakes without the Arduino involved.

Handshake 1: This is an HDMI 1.4 device [image: HDMI 1.4 device]

Handshake 2: This is another HDMI 1.4 device[image: Another HDMI 1.4 device]

You can see that the handshakes are the same. 
My code only works on handshake 1.

Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work on the other devices ?

Does it has to do with the Start/Restart ?

Regards !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in HDMI/DDC, but I have some theories to remove potential problems:

1. "Wire.onRequest/Wire.onReceive" could be before "digitalWrite(2, HIGH)", to really represent "OK, you can send me data now" (Arduino isn't the fastest HW, and Arduino libs add extra overhead - lots of condition races can occur);
2. You could use "Write.write(did, 256)", instead of writing one byte to I2C then another via serial (again, racing conditions, specially since serial writing is slow);
3. If I'm not misunderstanding, the byte received from HDMI means the byte you should start transmitting EDID (ex: for "0", do a "Wire.write(edid, 128)", for "0x80", do a "Wire.write(edid + 0x80)"). This is a common approach for reading from PROM chips. HDMI have a 5V pin to allow PROM reading from turned-off devices, and byte 127 from EDID means "I may have more 128 bytes for you".
4. Are you doing simple tests, with unmodified data? Ex: read EDID from device X, test that same EDID, then test with modified data?